# why doesn't my initialValue() of ThreadLocal work?

Tags: java, multithreading, initialization, thread-local

I want to test usage of `ThreadLocal` object in java,but it seems that my initialValue() not works. And I auctually call `get()` before `set()`, it should return variable `ID` that is 100 as expected. Here is my code:

```
public class UsageThreadLocal implements Runnable {
    private AnotherThreadID<Long> var;

    public UsageThreadLocal(AnotherThreadID<Long> v) {
        this.var = v;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            print("var getThreadID =" + var.get());
            Thread.sleep(200);
            var.set(Thread.currentThread().getId());
            print("var getThreadID =" + var.get());
        } catch (InterruptedException x) {
        }
    }

    private static void print(String msg) {
        String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        System.out.println(name + ": " + msg);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnotherThreadID<Long> tid = new AnotherThreadID<Long>() {
            @Override
            public Long initialValue() {
                ID = new Long(100);
                System.out.println("I'm in initialValue()!");
                return ID;
            }
        };
        UsageThreadLocal shared = new UsageThreadLocal(tid);

        try {
            Thread threadA = new Thread(shared, "threadA");
            threadA.start();

            Thread.sleep(50);

            Thread threadB = new Thread(shared, "threadB");
            threadB.start();

            Thread.sleep(50);

            Thread threadC = new Thread(shared, "threadC");
            threadC.start();
        } catch (InterruptedException x) {
        }
    }
}

class AnotherThreadID<T> extends ThreadLocal<T> {
    public T ID;

    @Override
    public void set(T newID) {
        ID = newID;
    }

    @Override
    public T get() {
        return ID;
    }

}
```

and executing result of my code:

```
threadA: var getThreadID =null
threadB: var getThreadID =null
threadC: var getThreadID =null
threadA: var getThreadID =9
threadB: var getThreadID =10
threadC: var getThreadID =11
```

What is the problem of my code or I misunderstand the usage of `ThreadLocal`?

Comment: All objects automatically inherit `Object`, need not to extend it explictly (`extends Object`)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the implementation of `AnotherThreadID`. `ThreadLocal` is to keep a value for each Thread, you override the `get()` and `set()` basically make it no long a `ThreadLocal`.

You may just remove `AnotherThreadID` class, and replace everywhere `AnotherThreadID` with `ThreadLocal`, then your code should work without further change.

Comment: Thanks@Kevin Wang. It works, that is to say, overriding the  ``get()`` or ``set()`` needs more complicated work?

Comment: @zhanghui Usually implementing `initialValue()` is enough. And if you take a look at the get() and set() in ThreadLocal, you will see better how it works. Honestly I don't see in what case they need to be overridden.

Comment: It means that I should regard ``get()`` or ``set()`` as basic method to use  for building behaviours what I want in the ``MyThreadLocal``  object ?

Comment: There is no simple rule saying one should or should not override the two methods. It really depends on your application.

Answer (score 0):

AnotherThreadID should be init by its thread，but you init it in the main thread. And you only have one AnotherThreadID instance.In fact,each thread should have an instance.